# How can I use Moose with Test::Class?

Tags: perl, moose, test-class

I'm currently refactoring a test suite built up by a colleague and would like to use `Test::Class[::Most]` while doing so. As I started I figured out I could really use a couple of `Moose` roles to decouple code a little bit. However, it seems it's not quite possible -- I'm getting error messages like this one:

```
Prototype mismatch: sub My::Test::Class::Base::blessed: none vs ($) at
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Sub/Exporter.pm line 896
```

So the question is: can I use `Moose` together with `Test::Class` and if so, how?

PS: The code goes like this:

```
package My::Test::Class::Base;
use Moose;
use Test::Class::Most;

with 'My::Cool::Role';

has attr => ( ... );
```

Comment: Related: [How can I mock Moose objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365578/how-can-i-mock-moose-objects)

Comment: There is always Test::Sweet, which is a Moose-based OO testing framework.  (It's not xUnit, because it uses Moose's existing concepts instead of inventing its own.)

Comment: Ooh, T::S looks neat.  Nice work there.  Won't get away with it at $job, but....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Test::Deep (loaded via Test::Most via Test::Class::Most) is exporting its own `blessed` along with a lot of other stuff it probably shouldn't be.  Its not documented.  Moose is also exporting the more common `Scalar::Util::blessed`.  Since `Scalar::Util::blessed` is fairly common, Test::Deep should not be exporting its own different `blessed`.

Unfortunately, there's no good way to stop it.  I'd suggest in My::Test::Class::Base doing the following hack:

```
package My::Test::Class::Base;

# Test::Class::Most exports Test::Most exports Test::Deep which exports
# an undocumented blessed() which clashes with Moose's blessed().
BEGIN {
    require Test::Deep;
    @Test::Deep::EXPORT = grep { $_ ne 'blessed' } @Test::Deep::EXPORT;
}

use Moose;
use Test::Class::Most;
```

and reporting the problem to [Test::Deep](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Test-Deep) and [Test::Most](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Test-Most).

Comment: I guess it's no use to report this problem, since it has been reported almost three years ago: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=27699
Thanks for your workaround, I'll add my comment to that bug report.

Comment: Report it to Test::Most.  It doesn't have to export everything from Test::Deep.

Answer (score 5):

You can squelch particular exports via (for example):

```
use Test::Deep '!blessed';
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just released an updated version of Test::Most. If you install 0.30, this issue goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Folks finding this page might also be interested to know about the various Test::Class-Moose mashup modules:

- [Test::Able](http://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aAble)
- [Test::Sweet](http://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aSweet)
- [Test::Class::Moose](http://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aClass%3a%3aMoose) (not yet on CPAN)

With any of these some amount of refactoring would required-- the syntax varies. HOwever, with  some amount of find-and-replace you may be able to make a fairly quick transition.

Comment: For those who are looking, I currently have an alpha of [Test::Class::Moose on github](https://github.com/Ovid/test-class-moose).

Comment: Test::Class::Moose has been on the CPAN for years now. I should have come along and mentioned that.